# Isolating select2 version doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 on my WordPress plugin and I need to isolate the version I load in order to avoid conflicts with other plugins also using Select2.

I have found [this answer](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3942) by [@Kevin Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359284/kevin-brown) where he proposes to use save the select2 function into a variable just after being loaded and before removing it to avoid issues with other loads:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<script>
   var myOwnSelect2 = $.fn.select2;
   delete $.fn.select2;
</script>
```

The problem I have is that it works in edit-post.php pages, but not anywhere else. I mean, "select" tags/elements are being replaced on edit-post.php pages but not at my plugin settings page. The code on each page looks like this:

**edit-post.php**

```
HTML

<div class="myplugin-metabox">
...
   <select name="_myplugin_item" class="searchable select2-hidden-accessible" data-placeholder="Select an item..." tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
      <option>...</option>
   </select>
...
</div>

Javascript

myOwnSelect2.call( $('.myplugin-metabox select'), { dropdownAutoWidth: true, minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity } );
```

**admin.php?page=myplugin**

```
HTML

<div id="myplugin-settings">
...
   <select id="option-1" name="myplugin-option-1" class="">
      <option value="all">...</option>
      ...
   </select>
...
</div>

Javascript

myOwnSelect2.call( $('#myplugin-settings select'), { dropdownAutoWidth: true, minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity } );
```

If I don't use any isolation method, everything within my plugin is working just fine... but I need the isolation because many other popular plugins load their own version/copy of Select2.

Javascript initializations are made on the same file. Keeping isolation, if I remove initialization for edit-post.php selects, selects on my plugin settings page doesn't get converted to Select2 dropdowns.

Any suggestion of what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the cause of the problem myself. I'm writing it here so it might be of help to others in my situation.

The thing was that I was referencing jQuery as "$", when I should have referenced it as "jQuery". Check out the code below:

**Didn't work (in my case)**:

```
<script>
   var myOwnSelect2 = $.fn.select2;
   delete $.fn.select2;
</script>
```

**Does work (in my case)**:

```
<script>
   var myOwnSelect2 = jQuery.fn.select2;
   delete jQuery.fn.select2;
</script>
```